# IE11 z-index issue -ms-device-fixed

Tags: html, css, windows, z-index, internet-explorer-11

I have the following html configuration

- header div with a message div set to position fixed with high z-index.
- bellow, content div with low z-index.

On scroll everything works perfect in IE11 on Windows 10. Problem is when overflow-y:auto is activated on the content div it will make the content above message.

Setting the message div with -ms-device-fixed instead of fixed will make the divs respect the z-indexes and remove the issue.

Why this is happening?

Comment: But what's the issue? It's more of a question I suppose. But take a look at the MS site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531140(v=vs.85).aspx where they explain the -ms-device-fixed property

Comment: thanks for reply.

problem relies in the fact that position fixed div gets overlaped when the scrollbar is displayed in the content. I found that -ms-device-fixed will make it display properly (BUT I don't see the relation between -ms-device-fixed and the scrollbar). 

I'm also interested if there are any other fixes for this matter. (I couldn't find other one).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find why content penetrate look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531188(v=vs.85).aspx

and about -ms-device-fixed property it seems that it just doesn't let content to be overflow in some way.